# Mustache does not work with @RestController but works with @Controller

Tags: spring-boot, mustache

I have a pre-existing `@RestController` in my Spring Boot app which I wanted to reuse with Mustache. Here is my sample function (in Kotlin) which is supposed to work with Mustache -

```
@RestController
class IndexController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    fun index(model: Model): String {
        /*model.addAttribute("title", "Test Time")*/
        model["title"] = "App Test"
        return "index"
    }
}
```

And this is my mustache file -

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{{title}}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/style.css"/>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <h3>Welcome!</h3>
        {{>footer}}
    </body>
</html>
```

When I run the above code and access localhost, I get the string "index" printed on it and nothing else. However, when I change `@RestController` to `@Controller` the localhost displays the website as expected.

Is it not possible to use `@RestContoller` with Mustache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@RestController` is basically `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`, meaning that your return of "index" is being evaluated into the actual string.

So no, there isn't an issue with using Mustache and `@RestController`, but `@RestController` returns a response body (not a view).

To get around this, you can change this into just a plain `@Controller` and for the other methods of your class that return JSON, add the `@ResponseBody` annotation to the method.